# Problema para enviar mensaje de correo: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, html

Buenas tardes saludos cordiales, estoy aprendiendo a enviar mensaje de correo desde mi proyecto PHP con un servidor local, me pueden apoyar, no logro enviar un mensaje de correo electrónico, me da como respuesta el mensaje de error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host, detallo el código:

Este es mi archivo HTML

```
    <form id="form1" class="well col-lg-12" action="enviar.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Nombre*</label>
        <input id="Nombre" type="text" name="Nombre" />

        <label>Email*</label>
        <input id="Email" type="email" name="Email" />

          <label>Mensaje*</label> 
         <textarea id="Mensaje" name="Mensaje" rows="4"></textarea>
         
          <label>archivo</label>
          <input type="file" name="adjunto" id="archivo-adjunto">

        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

este es mi archivo en PHP

```
<?php
    //Capturar datos del formulario en variables
    $Nombre = $_POST['Nombre'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Mensaje = $_POST['Mensaje'];
    $archivo = $_FILES['adjunto'];

    require("archivosmail/class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->From     = $Email;
    $mail->FromName = $Nombre;
    //*****Dirección a la que llegaran los mensajes*****
    $mail->AddAddress("mail@mail.com");
   
    // Aquí van los datos que apareceran en el correo que se envia
    $mail->WordWrap = 50; 
    $mail->IsHTML(true);     
    $mail->Subject  =  "Contacto";
    $mail->Body     =  "Nombre: $Nombre \n<br />".    
    "Email: $Email \n<br />".    
    "Mensaje: $Mensaje \n<br />";
    $mail->AddAttachment($archivo['tmp_name'], $archivo['name']);
    
    //*****Datos del servidor SMTP para hacer posible el envio del correo*****
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465"; //Servidor de Salida.
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
    $mail->Username = "rajaen.boleta@gmail.com"; //Correo Electrónico
    $mail->Password = "*****"; //Contraseña
    
    if ($mail->Send())
        echo "<script>alert('Formulario enviado exitosamente.');</script>";
    else
        echo "<script>alert('Error al enviar el formulario');</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa configuración es de la documentación oficial?

Te pondré como tengo mi config en un form que funciona a diario, pueda que sea porque divido las variables según ejemplos del sitio oficial.

```
<?php
    //Server settings
    // $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';
    // Pass dado por Google especial para esta App
    $mail->Password = '*ocst$$#$&hglfwmllrgvn';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port = 465;
```